# Ionic 2 Android Toolbar Buttons are Stacking

Tags: android, html, ionic2, navbar, toolbar

I am trying to add three buttons on the far right side to my Ionic 2 Application.

It works just fine on a chrome browser and iOS, however, on Android, no matter what I do two buttons will stack.

If I put all three in `<ion-buttons end>` I get 
this:
[image]

If I try putting the first two in `<ion-buttons start>` and one in `<ion-buttons end>` I get this:
[image]

A similar thing happens if I put one in `<ion-buttons start>` and one in  `<ion-buttons end>`

Here is my header HTML:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar color="primary">
        <button ion-button menuToggle>
          <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    <ion-title>Cobblestone</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="openSearch()">
          <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="openLocations($event)">
          <ion-icon name="pin"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="openCart()">
          <ion-icon name="cart"></ion-icon>
      </button>
     </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

I thought it might be related to the menu button, but removing it did not change anything.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ionic 2 navbar/toolbar has a sequence of positioning itens on it, going from 0 to 7. Go to the bottom of the [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/toolbar/Toolbar/) and check it on ios and android scss variables.

So they go like this:

```
$toolbar-order-md: (
  back-button: 0,
  menu-toggle-start: 1,
  buttons-left: 2,
  content: 3, 
  buttons-start: 4,
  buttons-end: 5,
  buttons-right: 6,
  menu-toggle-end: 7, )
```

So what you need to do is follow the buttons order using the attributes **start**, **end** and **right** like this:

```
<ion-buttons start>
     <button ion-button icon-only>
         <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
     </button>
 </ion-buttons>
 <ion-buttons end>
     <button ion-button icon-only>
         <ion-icon name="pin"></ion-icon>
     </button>
 </ion-buttons>
 <ion-buttons right>
     <button ion-button icon-only>
         <ion-icon name="cart"></ion-icon>
     </button>
 </ion-buttons>
```

Hope it helps :D

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you so much! I find it weird that I couldn't find anything like this with Google searches, one would think that this would be a somewhat common problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very easy fix!, [based on this](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/6844).

use `left` instead of `start` 
and
use `right` instead of `end`

Then, you will see a consistent alignment on both `ios` and `android`.